# Problems with installing scikit-learn on Fedora

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I have some problems while installing scikit-learn on Fedora 23 using pip

`pip install scikit-learn`

Here's what I get

> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-MPbvR0/scikit-learn/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-k_kxgh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MPbvR0/scikit-learn

What may the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get around the problem.  Download and install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which is Python + 195 packages including scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally managed to get back to it and everything's great now :)